# How to make table triggier based on date?

Tags: email, triggers

Is there a way to make a table trigger that sends an email once a date attribute get 30 days from the date listed?  e.g. 07/31/2020 is listed in the table and when it gets to 07/01/2020 in real life, an email is sent out to notify someone. it would be a 30 day in advance notification.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean some specific database ?

Comment: yes a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an SQL Job, which will executed on daily basis and send db email once it get date difference (datediff(D, getdate(),'2020-07-31) equals to 30 OR change in the table to trigger

Comment: thanks, not real sure how to do that but thank you.